# Configuring logrotate without root access (per user log rotation)

Tags: users, cron, logrotate

How best can logrotate be configured, on a per-user basis, to rotate files in the home directory of the user, under control of a per-user `crontab -e`?

Answer (score 34):

Try this procedure:

1. create `/home/user/logrotate` folder

   ```
   mkdir /home/user/logrotate
   ```
2. create `/home/user/logrotate/my.conf` configuration file with logrotate directive as you need
3. create `/home/user/logrotate/cronjob` to run logrotate every day at 2:30 AM (this is an example)

   ```
   30 2 * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate -s /home/user/logrotate/status /home/user/logrotate/my.conf > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```
4. check your configuration file syntax:

   ```
   logrotate -d /home/user/logrotate/my.conf
   ```
5. configure `crontab` to run `logrotate`
   (**Warning**: This removes existing entries in your crontab. Use `crontab -e` to manually add the line from step 3 to an existing crontab):

   ```
   crontab /home/user/logrotate/cronjob
   ```

After this last command, `logrotate` will rotate file as described in `/home/user/logrotate/my.conf` and save log file status in `/home/user/logrotate/status`.

Use:

```
crontab -r   # remove crontab activities for user
crontab -l   # to list crontab activity for user
crontab -e   # edit user crontab entries
```

Here is [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/logrotate.8.html) and [crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/crontab.5.html) man page.

Comment: Very instructive. Maybe it should be mentioned that 'crontab <file>' removes all previously configured cronjobs. This just happened to me - luckily I had a backup :)

Comment: @pederpansen thanks for having improved my answer :)

Comment: Thanks to the `-s` parameter will avoid `error: error creating unique temp file: Permission denied`.

Comment: Running as normal user I get

`error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp: Permission denied`

Comment: @realtebo parameter -s /home/user/logrotate/status should avoid this problem. Did you use it?

Comment: @Lety, thanks, `-s` param solves the problem, so I can run as normal user, specifi my config file to execute and also using `-s` I can specify state file. Thanks, really